# C++ SDL header file errors

Tags: c++, header, sdl

I'm following a tutorial and it said at one point it should compile, but it errored.

To find out why I just used their code instead of mine and have just pasted all theirs in, however, this is picking up errors. It's in a header file, I've placed the errors below the code

```
#ifndef _CApp_H_ 
 #define _CApp_H_ 

#include <SDL.h> 

class CApp { 
 private: 
  bool Running; 

 public: 
  CApp(); 
  int OnExecute(); 

 public: 
  bool OnInit(); 
  void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event); 
  void OnLoop(); 
  void OnRender(); 
  void OnCleanup(); 
}; 

#endif
```

Errors:

Syntax error before CAPP, on line 6. 
Syntax error before the first {, on line 6. 
Syntax error before : on line 14. 
Line 25 before }

All files are declared. I have another error, too, here:

```
#include "CApp.h" 

void CApp::OnCleanup() { 
}
```

Before :. it doesn't give more description than that apart from it's on line 3.

Comment: For some reason some of the preprocessor statements lost their hash and resized, but they have a hash before them in my source.  EDIT: fixed

Comment: Don't use HTML tags to post your code, just select it, then hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Apears I did a late fix. Apologies. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the SDL.h file in your include path?  Nothing in the example jumps out at me as wrong.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks and I've set it as a linked library, so I'd assume so.

Comment: If you create a simple header that doesn't do anything but include that header do you get a compiler error?

Comment: No, It just told me that it had nothing to be done when I compiled it individually, so I don't think so.

Comment: I think I've solved it, I'm using Code::Block's SDL feature, but I got rid of the code that was there originaly, so I might try using an ordinary project and link to SDL and see if that works.

Comment: Nope, it's the file. It doesn't like any of it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a proper answer to your question, but...

I would highly recommend switching to SFML instead of SDL. It's essentially a modernized, object-oriented SFML written in C++. It has many advantages over SDL (such as fully hardware-accelerated 2D drawing). Check it out if you'd like.

Comment: Nah, SFML is not that good. SDL is used in many commercial products. Plus, it's easy to make your own 2D acceleration via OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably located in a path. Try putting # include "SDL\SDL.h".